# Update MahApps.Metro from Version 0.13.1 to a higher one

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mahapps.metro, flipview

I wanted to finally update my MahApps.Metro with the NuGet Manager for my Project.
In one WPF Window I use the FlipView Control and when I update Metro I always end up with an NullPointer Exception in the FlipView class.

It does not matter if I update to version 0.14 or 1.0.0 or 1.5.0 - it always crashes.

When I exclude the FlipView it starts but every window I call with .ShowDialog() does not show up.

Did anyone experienced the same?

Comment: Kai do you perhaps have an example stack trace and have you checked for a similar issue on the Mahapps Github issues list, here is an example of a search https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20null%20reference%20

Comment: I recommend to close this topic, as your question was [answered at Github](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/3038).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question can be closed, answer is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/3038#issuecomment-327208631)

Summary: I used a custom Style Template which caused the trouble. Removing it solved the problem.